# Pass python variable to bash shell using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, git, bash, shell

I need to change git tags on the "fly". Currently I'm comparing files between different git tags using a mix of python and bash. Using subprocess I am attempting to run a subprocess(["git checkout", tag]) which after some tinkering I am unable to get to work. It appears as though the git checkout command isn't actually doing anything and a file within the given tag isn't found causing my script to hang and/or fail.

To give more detail. There are a list of CSVs within our git repos, I need to find those CSVs for the given versions (tags), compare them, and then put them in to a text file containing removals, additions, etc.

At the moment, as said above, I am unable to switch the tag that I'm on using subprocess. I attempted os.system(arg) as well but it only takes one argument and is useful for my needs.

I'll be using re and difflib later in the script. Also the bash script works without issue, I entertained/tested the idea of using environment variables in bash but it didn't seem to work as they aren't able to be called later on.

My code is below:

```
import os
import subprocess
import re
import difflib

# ---- run githubcompare.sh script ---- #
subprocess.call(["[bash script file path]"])

# ---- store tag info in lists to separate additions, removals, and shared info ---- #
# ---- set lists to store info in files ---- #
removals = []  # file one
additions = []  # file two
shared = []  # both files

# ---- store tag 1 file in removals list ---- #
with open("[file path]","r") as infile1:
    for line in infile1.readlines():
        removals.append(line)

# ---- store tag 2 file in additions list ---- #
with open("[file path]","r") as infile2:
    for line in infile2.readlines():
        additions.append(line)

# ---- set list length to appropriate var ---- #
removalsLength = len(removals)
additionsLength = len(additions)

# ---- set x variable to longest list length ---- #
if removalsLength >= additionsLength:
    x = removalsLength
elif removalsLength < additionsLength:
    x = additionsLength
else:
    print("Error 512: Something broke setting the length of x for removals length and additions length.")
    print("Printing var content of removalsLength and additionsLength.")
    print("removalsLength:", removalsLength, "\nadditionsLength:", additionsLength)

# ---- separate lists to removals, additions, and shared content where appropriate ---- #
i = 0
while i < x:
    if i > len(removals):
        print("Removals structure is done checking additions structure.")
    elif i <= len(removals):
        if removals[i] in additions:
            var = removals[i]
            shared.append(var)
            removals.remove(var)
            additions.remove(var)
    else:
        print("Error 612: Something broke evaluating i incrementer to removals length.")
        print("Printing i content:", i)
    if i > len(additions):
        print("Additions structure is done checking removals structure.")
    elif i <= len(additions):
        if additions[i] in removals:
            var = additions[i]
            shared.append(var)
            removals.remove(var)
            additions.remove(var)
    else:
        print("Error 612: Something broke evaluating i incrementer to additions length.")
        print("Printing i content:", i)
    i += 1

# ---- get tags into array from taglist.txt file ---- #
tagList = []
tagListPre = []
with open("[file path]", "r") as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        tagListPre.append(line)
for i in tagListPre:
    tagList.append(i.strip("\n"))

# ---- get content from directory files and write to final files for comparison ---- #
removalsList = []
additionsList = []
removalsData = []
additionsData = []

# ---- format removals text files ---- #
firstTag = tagList[0]
with open("[file path]","r") as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        line1 = line.strip("\n")
        os.chdir(line1)
        subprocess.call(["[bash script containing git checkout]", str(firstTag)])
        for lineRemoval in removals:
            lineRemoval = lineRemoval.strip("\n").replace('//', '/')
            with open(lineRemoval, "r") as inf:
                for removalLine in inf.readlines():
                    if removalLine == "\n":
                        continue
                    else:
                        removalsData.append(removalLine.strip("\n"))
for z in removalsData:
    temp = z.split(",")[0].strip("\"").strip("\n")
    removalsList.append(temp)

# ---- format additions text files ---- #
secondTag = tagList[1]
with open("[file path containing github repo file locations.txt]", "r") as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        os.chdir(line)
        subprocess.Popen(["git checkout", str(secondTag)])
        for y in additions:
            y = y.strip("\n").replace('//', '/')
            with open(y, "r") as inf:
                for line in inf.readlines():
                    if line == "\n":
                        continue
                    else:
                        additionsData.append(line.strip("\n"))
for aa in removalsData:
    temp = aa.split(",")[0].strip("\"").strip("\n")
    additionsList.append(temp)
```

So far I have attempted passing the tag variable in as is, using a file to run the git checkout with the python tag arg, setting the tags as environment variables, hard coding the tag to see if it would work when passed explicitly, among a few other things.

I was able to resolve this by properly calling the shell with subprocess.

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "checkout", tag], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Have you tried `["git", "checkout", tag]`?

Comment: Yeah, that was the other one I couldn't remember to mention. subprocess.Popen(["git", "checkout", firstTag], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)  is one I'm currently attempting but its still not switching the tag

Comment: Did you try to use the [`subprocess.check_output()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) ? And so you could print the output of your command ?

Comment: You do understand that the process is not yet finished when `Popen` returns, right? You should at a minimum save the returned object and then call its `communicate` method to find out what git is telling you.

Comment: Have you tried this way `subprocess.call("git checkout tag",shell=True)`?

Comment: As Arton say, you need the "shell=True" argument as you do some modification in the git repo.